# How can I toggle suggestion details in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

In many VS Code materials, such as the official tutorials, there's a small panel to the right of the autocomplete suggestions:
[image: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac]

However, I don't have these quick infos; my autocomplete looks like this:
[image: i use arch btw]

I can reproduce the same thing (i.e. the panel to the right of the suggestions doesn't appear) on my Windows machine. Is there a setting I need to toggle?

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle suggestion details using any of the following default keyboard shortcuts (may need to use <kbd>cmd</kbd> on macOS instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>):

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+i",
  "command": "toggleSuggestionDetails",
  "when": "suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+space",
  "command": "toggleSuggestionDetails",
  "when": "suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
},
```

You can also [customize keyboard shortcuts to your liking](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor).

Of course, this requires that the extension which contributed the suggestion / [`CompletionItem`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem) populated the `detail` and `documentation` properties, or implements for them to be populated by [`resolveCompletionItem`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItemProvider.resolveCompletionItem), or there would be nothing to show in the details widget.