# How to show IntelliSense attributes's description in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I typed `Ctrl + Space` to exec `interactiveEditor.start`, I hope its show the `list-query` description when I typed `li-` and selected `list-query`. but I must typed complete `list-query` and moved mouse to this word

[image]

[image]

Comment: "_When I typed Ctrl + Space to exec interactiveEditor.start_" ummmmm... what? do you mean "to trigger suggestions"? And do you know you can press ctrl+space again to toggle the suggestions detail widget?

Comment: yeah, I know, but it not works

Comment: please provide enough detail to reproduce this behaviour. what language are you writing? what dependencies are required? what project configuration is required? what VS Code extensions are required? Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.

Comment: there's related info in https://stackoverflow.com/q/76848195/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/77608184/11107541