# Show quick documentation near Code Completion window for selected word in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, documentation, code-completion

Is it possible to show quick documentation for the Selected word in code completion window in Vs Code with C# ?
Quick documentation shortcut is showing documentation for the word behind the cursor instead of selected word in Code Completion window.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: ... suggestion details? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76848195/11107541 does that not solve your problem?